# Calling custom method from another custom method

Tags: ractivejs

When a custom method invokes another custom method, any `this.get()` references in the 2nd method will fail. Here's a simple example ([or full JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aq4w3okr/3/)):

```
var ractive = Ractive({
    ...
    data: {
        Title: "Just an example",

        Method1: function() { return this.get("Title"); },
        Method2: function() { return this.get("Method1")(); }
    }
});
....

<div id="template">
    {{ Method1() }}   <!-- This works. It outputs "Just as example" -->
    {{ Method2() }}   <!-- This throws an error -->
</div>
```

Invoking `Method1()` on its own works fine but it fails when invoked by `Method2()`. The error is "undefined is not a function" because `this.get()` is undefined in this context.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to pass on context when calling that method:

```
Method2: function() { return this.get("Method1").call(this); }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aq4w3okr/5/